# Debian increase sort performance

Tags: bash, sorting, debian

i am currently having issues to increase the speed of the sort command in `debian`.
I got a File that contains only Hexadecimal numbers with the length of 11 digest each.
I used the following commands to sort a file with the size of `1.6GB` and got the following benchmarks.

```
sort h.txt -o h2.txt ( 3.03m )
sort h.txt -n -o h2.txt ( 2.54m )
```

As i only need to sort the first two digest i used the following command:

```
sort h.txt -n -k 1.1,1.2 -o h2.txt ( 3.08m )
LC_ALL=C sort h.txt -n -k 1.1,1.2 -o h2.txt ( 1.01m )
```

Can you image some other parameters that i can pass to increase the speed of sorting?

Comment: Please show a few lines of input.

Comment: You could change your `locale` settings to use the `C` to speed-up things, change it locally to the `sort` command as `LC_ALL=C sort h.txt -n -k 1.1,1.2 -o h2.txt` and see if it is impacting

Comment: How much RAM do you have? You could try increasing the buffer size, see also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146013/what-should-be-the-buffer-size-for-the-sort-command)

Comment: i got 32GB of RAM, i edited the question LC_ALL=C did a big impact on performance

Comment: @MarekSalzinger GNU sort has a `--parallel` flag so you can use all your cpu cores if you have more than 8 which is default i think.

Comment: I don't got more then 8 cores and setting the buffer didn't help me out, it seems like if i leave the buffer parameter away it will gain better speed